# Programming a multiplayer game with a PhP/MySQL server, and JavaScript/jQuery clients

Tags: php, jquery

Here is the situation. I would like to develop a game based on content delivered by MediaWiki. MediaWiki is PhP based and has MySQL as database. So far, I did the client side animations using JavaScript and jQuery.

The game doesn't have to be strictly real-time. I simply want to be notified when the person I am playing against makes a move, within a second or two.

Do you have suggestions about suitable approaches I might want to consider?

Comment: look up comet ajax techniques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are into new programming approaches, you also may be interested in [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and the whole [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) thing. [This video on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0-HD6Z1mlo) gives you an idea of what you can do with WebSockets (also check out the related ones).

Comment: According to Wikipedia, WebSockets are disabled by default on Firefox. It seems most browsers don't support WebSockets. Is that still true?

Comment: @Randomblue Good point, but AFAIK, it's not true since the beta of FireFox 4 anymore.